# how to set up background image for edge modelling a head?

Tags: modeling, image, edges

I'm looking to try out edge modeling a human head in a method similar to the one shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86JiuZpbi_w). I plan on using this [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARush.png), but I can't seem to be able to find a way to set it up like in that video. The method he used to add those reference images is gone in 2.8, and I don't know how to achieve the same effect.

What should I do? What's the best way to set up a background/reference image for edge modeling a head? Are there any ways to do it like in that video?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a background/refeence image.
You can then control its appearance in the properties panel.

*Add > Image > Reference/Background*

[image]

*You can adjust the appearance, position, opacity*

[image]